# Vibration transducer to ADC of STM32

Tags: operational-amplifier, stm32, adc, transducer, vibration

I'm trying to design a circuit to read the vibration value from a vibration transducer and I need some help with it.

The signal from the transducer has DC component of 12 volts and a varying AC component from 1 mV to 200 mV with frequency starting from 4.5 Hz to 1000 Hz. The AC component is dependent on the amount of vibration.

I'm planning to read the signal with STM32 12 bit ADC with a opamp in between them.

Questions:
Am I on the right track with this design?
Should I use the internal opamp of the STM32 or an external one?
If I should use an external opamp, any recommendations?
Is the STM32 ADC a good choice for this?
Any LDO recommendations for 3.3 volts?
Should there be any decoupling from the output of the opamp to the ADC?

[image: LT spice circuit]

Comment: 1mV is quite a small signal. What resolution do you need at this level?

Comment: @Jon Just to detect correctly 1mV signal change from the transducer with the ADC.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD7LZ0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**(1)**

First i would use a Z-Inverter (possibly with Lowpass filter attached) to
couple the signal into the PCB with a know impedance.

**(2)**

I would then AC-Couple the AC-Component of the signal, to get rid of the DC part.

**(3)**

I would then scale the ADC-Component to use the ADC full-scale range.

**(4)**

I would add a DC-offset to center the signal at half the ADC-Range and feed it into the ADC.

**Working Circuit**

[image]

**NOTE:** R5 is used to scale the AC-Component in such a way, that is uses the entire full scale range of 0V<->VREF

This produces the response:

[image]

Of course, you have to use more specific component values!

Comment: Could you elaborate your circuit a little more so I could learn, mainly the Z-inverter part of it. What are the benefits of using your circuit over my original one? Any op-amp suggestions for it? I'm really new to op-amps and ADCs but would like to learn more about them.